# How do I know if my I2C interface is working properly?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, i2c, c, embedded

I have an [MSP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN) ([MSP-EXP430FR6989 launchpad](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP-EXP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN)) interfacing with a [MAX30102](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/sensor-interface/MAX30102.html) Pulse Oximeter and Heart Rate sensor IC via I2C, I have only one master and one slave.

According to the pseudo-code in the [MAX30102 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX30102.pdf):

The peseudo code:

```
//First Interaction
START
send address (0x57) + write
write register address of FIFO_WR_PTR (0x04)
REPEATED START
send address (0x57) + read
read FIFO_WR_PTR
STOP

//processing
//Second interaction
```

Since I am new to programming I2C interfaces, I decided to only write a code for the first interaction, test it, and see how it goes.

This is the code:

//code

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

#define FACLK       32768
#define TIME        1 //1 sec
#define TMR_COUNT   (FACLK*TIME)

uint8_t WritePointer = 0;


#define MAX30102_SLAVE_ADDR         /*0x59*/0x57// 101 0111
#define MAX30102_FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR   0x04//0x55//0x04
//register addresses



// 1st interaction: S SLA/W (A) FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR (A) SR SLA/R (A) (FIFO_WR_PTR) NACK P  1st interaction

// Processing NUM_OF_SAMPLES = 4
//NUM_OF_AVAILABLE_SAMPLES = (FIFO_WR_PTR - FIFO_RD_PTR)/3
//if(NUM_OF_SAMPLES <= NUM_OF_AVAILABLE_SAMPLES){} else {NUM_OF_SAMPLES = NUM_OF_AVAILABLE_SAMPLES)

// 2nd interaction: S SLA/W (ACK) FIFO_DATA (ACK) Sr SLA/R (ACK) (LED1[23:16]) ACK (LED1[15:8]) ACK (LED1[7:0]) ACK
//                   (LED2[23:16]) ACK (LED2[15:8]) ACK (LED2[7:0]) NACK P


/*
 * Private Variables
 */

void configClock(void);
void configTimer (void);
void configI2C (void);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    
    configClock ();
    configTimer ();
    configI2C ();// eUSCI B0 I2C
    

    _BIS_SR (GIE);//enable global interrupt

    while(1);


    return 0;
}

void configI2C (void)
{
    //config P1.6 SDA P1.7 SCL
    P1SEL1 &= ~ (BIT6 | BIT7);
    P1SEL0 |= (BIT6 | BIT7);


    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;//put it on a restart mode to config
    UCB0CTLW0 |= (UCMST | UCMODE_3 | UCSSEL__SMCLK);// i2c master cs smclk
    UCB0BRW = 10;//100kbps /*4 300 kbps */
    UCB0IFG &= ~UCTXIFG0;
    UCB0I2CSA = MAX30102_SLAVE_ADDR;
    UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;//release for operation

    UCB0IE |= (UCTXIE0 | UCRXIE0);
}

void configClock (void)
{
    CSCTL0 = CSKEY;
    CSCTL1 = 0x0000;//DCO 1MHz
    CSCTL2 |= (SELA__LFXTCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK);
}

void configTimer (void)
{
    //one second delay
    //isr
    TA0CTL |= (TASSEL__ACLK | MC__UP);//cs aclk up mode
    TA0CCTL0 |= CCIE;
    TA0CCTL0 &= ~CCIFG;
    TA0CCR0 = TMR_COUNT;
}


#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void TimerA0_ISR (void)
{
    //first interaction
    //static int flag = 0;

    /*if(!flag)
    {
        UCB0CTLW0 |= (UCTR | UCTXSTT);//W and START
        flag = 1;
    }*/

    UCB0CTLW0 |= (UCTR | UCTXSTT);//W and START LINE A

    TA0CCTL0 &= ~CCIFG;
}

//first interaction
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void eUSCI_B0_I2C_ISR (void)
{
    static int counter = 0;

    switch(UCB0IV)
    {
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            UCB0TXBUF = MAX30102_FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR;
            counter++;
        }

        else
        {
            UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;//R
            UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;//repeated start
            counter = 0;
        }
        break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:
        WritePointer = UCB0RXBUF;
        //UCB0IFG &= ~UCRXIFG0;
        UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

However when I debugged it using the IDE and an oscilloscope:

These are the strange things that happen:

- when I stepped into line A `UCB0CTLW0 |= (UCTR | UCTXSTT);` this is the waveform I got, it only has 8 bits instead of 9, how ever the address is right (`101 0111`) and the right command

[image]

- The data I am sending is 0x04, `UCB0TXBUF = 0x04`, however in the oscilloscope it is 0x02

[image]

- After the Repeated Start, I expected around 18 periods, but here I see alot more periods, even the value of the `FIFO_WR_PTR` or `UCB0RXBUF` is 0

[image]

- After setting the UCTXSTP bit the SDA and SCL lines remains low, I have to remove power from the MAX30102 IC in order to reset the lines back to High (the only time it gets pulled high is when I add `WritePointer = UCB0RXBUF`, the `UCRXIFG0` gets toggled several times before it exits the isr).

---

- How do I know if the interface is working correctly, what should I expect from the first interaction?
- Is it normal to get such waveforms, or does it mean there is something wrong with the I2C interface?

Kindly assist me with this issue. Your help is truly appreciated.

---

EDIT1

This is what I understood from the MSP430 user guide, when the eUSCI B0 is in I2C Transmitter mode, when it receives a Slave ACK, the `UCB0TXIFG0` is set automatically, and when `UB0IV` is read it gets reset or cleared.

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT 2

I have rewritten the code, it is based on Texas Instrument MSP430FR6989 code example *msp430fr69xx_eusci_i2c_standard_master.c*, I took what is relevant from the code and pasted it into mine, however I don't see any part of a code related to watching the Slave's ACK/NACK or sending a Master's ACK/NACK, I always presumed this is done automatically.

- enable TX isr, transmit slave address (0x57) + Write Mode
- At USCI_B0 isr transmit register address (0x04)
- enters the tx isr again, then switch to RX mode: enable RX isr, clear `UCTR`, set `UCTXSTT`
- wait till `UCTXSTT` is cleared (START condition already generated)]
- set UCTXSTP bit for a STOP condition, during STOP, the Master will receive the remaining data before generating a NACK and stopping.
- at the RX isr store the RX buffer in a variable, and disable RX isr.

---

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDR          0x57
#define FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR    0x04

//S SLA/W ACK FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR ACK SR SLA /R ACK DATA NACK P

enum I2C_STATE
{
    IdleMode,
    TransmitRegAddrMode,
    SwitchToRXMode,
    ReceiveDataMode,
    TransmitDataMode
};


enum I2C_STATE MasterI2CMode = IdleMode;

void configClock ();
void initI2C ();
void I2C_MasterWriteReg (uint8_t, uint8_t);
//void I2C_MasterReadReg (uint8_t);

uint8_t TransmitRegAddr = 0;
uint8_t ReceiveReg = 0;


int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    
    configClock ();
    initI2C ();

    I2C_MasterWriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR,FIFO_WR_PTR_ADDR);
    //I2C_MasterReadReg();

    //eUSCI B0 I2C config


    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void configClock (void)
{
    CSCTL0 = CSKEY;
    CSCTL1 = 0x0000;//DCO 1MHz
    CSCTL2 |= (SELA__LFXTCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK);
}

void initI2C()
{
    //config P1.6 SDA P1.7 SCL
    P1SEL1 &= ~ (BIT6 | BIT7);
    P1SEL0 |= (BIT6 | BIT7);

    UCB0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB0BRW = 10;                            // fSCL = SMCLK/10 = ~100kHz
    UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
    UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE |= UCNACKIE;//enable NACK ISR (TX and RX?)
}

void I2C_MasterWriteReg (uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr)
{
    MasterI2CMode = TransmitRegAddrMode;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;
    UCB0I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB0IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG0 | UCRXIFG0);//clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE0; // disable rx interrupt
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE0; // enable TX isr

    __bis_SR_register(GIE);

    UCB0CTLW0 |= (UCTR | UCTXSTT);//isr tx start condition
    //__bis_SR_register(GIE);//enable global isr and lpm0
}

#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void eUSCI_B0_I2C_ISR (void)
{
    switch(UCB0IV)
    {
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:
        switch(MasterI2CMode)
        {
        case TransmitRegAddrMode:
            UCB0TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
            MasterI2CMode = SwitchToRXMode;
            break;
        case SwitchToRXMode:
            UCB0IE |= UCRXIE0;//enable rx isr
            UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE0; // disable tx isr
            UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCTR; //R
            MasterI2CMode = ReceiveDataMode;
            UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;

            while((UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT));//until a complete start happened

            UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;

            break;
        case TransmitDataMode:
            //UCB0TXBUF = 0x0A;
            //MasterI2CMode = SwitchToRXMode;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:
        ReceiveReg = UCB0RXBUF;
        MasterI2CMode = IdleMode;
        UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE0;
        //__bic_SR_register(LPM0_bits);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

---

*msp430fr69xx_eusci_i2c_standard_master.c*

```
//******************************************************************************
//   MSP430FR69xx Demo - eUSCI_B0, I2C Master multiple byte TX/RX
//
//   Description: I2C master communicates to I2C slave sending and receiving
//   3 different messages of different length. I2C master will enter LPM0 mode
//   while waiting for the messages to be sent/receiving using I2C interrupt.
//   ACLK = NA, MCLK = SMCLK = DCO 16MHz.
//
//                                     /|\ /|\
//                   MSP430FR6989      4.7k |
//                 -----------------    |  4.7k
//            /|\ |             P1.7|---+---|-- I2C Clock (UCB0SCL)
//             |  |                 |       |
//             ---|RST          P1.6|-------+-- I2C Data (UCB0SDA)
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//
//   Nima Eskandari and Ryan Meredith
//   Texas Instruments Inc.
//   January 2018
//   Built with CCS V7.3
//******************************************************************************

#include <msp430.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//******************************************************************************
// Pin Config ******************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#define LED_OUT     P1OUT
#define LED_DIR     P1DIR
#define LED0_PIN    BIT0
#define LED1_PIN    BIT1

//******************************************************************************
// Example Commands ************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#define SLAVE_ADDR  0x48

/* CMD_TYPE_X_SLAVE are example commands the master sends to the slave.
 * The slave will send example SlaveTypeX buffers in response.
 *
 * CMD_TYPE_X_MASTER are example commands the master sends to the slave.
 * The slave will initialize itself to receive MasterTypeX example buffers.
 * */

#define CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE      0
#define CMD_TYPE_1_SLAVE      1
#define CMD_TYPE_2_SLAVE      2

#define CMD_TYPE_0_MASTER      3
#define CMD_TYPE_1_MASTER      4
#define CMD_TYPE_2_MASTER      5

#define TYPE_0_LENGTH   1
#define TYPE_1_LENGTH   2
#define TYPE_2_LENGTH   6

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE     20

/* MasterTypeX are example buffers initialized in the master, they will be
 * sent by the master to the slave.
 * SlaveTypeX are example buffers initialized in the slave, they will be
 * sent by the slave to the master.
 * */

uint8_t MasterType2 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {'F', '4', '1', '9', '2', 'B'};
uint8_t MasterType1 [TYPE_1_LENGTH] = { 8, 9};
uint8_t MasterType0 [TYPE_0_LENGTH] = { 11};


uint8_t SlaveType2 [TYPE_2_LENGTH] = {0};
uint8_t SlaveType1 [TYPE_1_LENGTH] = {0};
uint8_t SlaveType0 [TYPE_0_LENGTH] = {0};

//******************************************************************************
// General I2C State Machine ***************************************************
//******************************************************************************

typedef enum I2C_ModeEnum{
    IDLE_MODE,
    NACK_MODE,
    TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    RX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    TX_DATA_MODE,
    RX_DATA_MODE,
    SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE,
    SWITHC_TO_TX_MODE,
    TIMEOUT_MODE
} I2C_Mode;


/* Used to track the state of the software state machine*/
I2C_Mode MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;

/* The Register Address/Command to use*/
uint8_t TransmitRegAddr = 0;

/* ReceiveBuffer: Buffer used to receive data in the ISR
 * RXByteCtr: Number of bytes left to receive
 * ReceiveIndex: The index of the next byte to be received in ReceiveBuffer
 * TransmitBuffer: Buffer used to transmit data in the ISR
 * TXByteCtr: Number of bytes left to transfer
 * TransmitIndex: The index of the next byte to be transmitted in TransmitBuffer
 * */
uint8_t ReceiveBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t RXByteCtr = 0;
uint8_t ReceiveIndex = 0;
uint8_t TransmitBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t TXByteCtr = 0;
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0;



/* I2C Write and Read Functions */

/* For slave device with dev_addr, writes the data specified in *reg_data
 *
 * dev_addr: The slave device address.
 *           Example: SLAVE_ADDR
 * reg_addr: The register or command to send to the slave.
 *           Example: CMD_TYPE_0_MASTER
 * *reg_data: The buffer to write
 *           Example: MasterType0
 * count: The length of *reg_data
 *           Example: TYPE_0_LENGTH
 *  */
I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count);

/* For slave device with dev_addr, read the data specified in slaves reg_addr.
 * The received data is available in ReceiveBuffer
 *
 * dev_addr: The slave device address.
 *           Example: SLAVE_ADDR
 * reg_addr: The register or command to send to the slave.
 *           Example: CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE
 * count: The length of data to read
 *           Example: TYPE_0_LENGTH
 *  */
I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count);
void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count);


I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;
    RXByteCtr = count;
    TXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB0I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB0IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts

    return MasterMode;

}


I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;

    //Copy register data to TransmitBuffer
    CopyArray(reg_data, TransmitBuffer, count);

    TXByteCtr = count;
    RXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB0I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB0IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts

    return MasterMode;
}

void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count)
{
    uint8_t copyIndex = 0;
    for (copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < count; copyIndex++)
    {
        dest[copyIndex] = source[copyIndex];
    }
}


//******************************************************************************
// Device Initialization *******************************************************
//******************************************************************************


void initGPIO()
{
    // Configure GPIO
    LED_OUT &= ~(LED0_PIN | LED1_PIN); // P1 setup for LED & reset output
    LED_DIR |= (LED0_PIN | LED1_PIN);

    // I2C pins
    P1SEL0 |= BIT6 | BIT7;
    P1SEL1 &= ~(BIT6 | BIT7);

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
}

void initClockTo16MHz()
{
    // Configure one FRAM waitstate as required by the device datasheet for MCLK
    // operation beyond 8MHz _before_ configuring the clock system.
    FRCTL0 = FRCTLPW | NWAITS_1;

    // Clock System Setup
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_0;                     // Set DCO to 1MHz

    // Set SMCLK = MCLK = DCO, ACLK = LFXTCLK (VLOCLK if unavailable)
    CSCTL2 = SELA__LFXTCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;

    // Per Device Errata set divider to 4 before changing frequency to
    // prevent out of spec operation from overshoot transient
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__4 | DIVS__4 | DIVM__4;   // Set all corresponding clk sources to divide by 4 for errata
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_4 | DCORSEL;           // Set DCO to 16MHz

    // Delay by ~10us to let DCO settle. 60 cycles = 20 cycles buffer + (10us / (1/4MHz))
    __delay_cycles(60);
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__1 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;   // Set all dividers to 1 for 16MHz operation
    CSCTL0_H = 0;                           // Lock CS registers
}

void initI2C()
{
    UCB0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB0BRW = 160;                            // fSCL = SMCLK/160 = ~100kHz
    UCB0I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
    UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE |= UCNACKIE;
}


//******************************************************************************
// Main ************************************************************************
// Send and receive three messages containing the example commands *************
//******************************************************************************

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    initClockTo16MHz();
    initGPIO();
    initI2C();

    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_0_MASTER, MasterType0, TYPE_0_LENGTH);
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_1_MASTER, MasterType1, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_2_MASTER, MasterType2, TYPE_2_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_0_SLAVE, TYPE_0_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType0, TYPE_0_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_1_SLAVE, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType1, TYPE_1_LENGTH);

    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, CMD_TYPE_2_SLAVE, TYPE_2_LENGTH);
    CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType2, TYPE_2_LENGTH);

    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);
    return 0;
}


//******************************************************************************
// I2C Interrupt ***************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = USCI_B0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_B0_VECTOR))) USCI_B0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  //Must read from UCB0RXBUF
  uint8_t rx_val = 0;
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB0IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
  {
    case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
      break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:                 // Vector 22: RXIFG0
        rx_val = UCB0RXBUF;
        if (RXByteCtr)
        {
          ReceiveBuffer[ReceiveIndex++] = rx_val;
          RXByteCtr--;
        }

        if (RXByteCtr == 1)
        {
          UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
        }
        else if (RXByteCtr == 0)
        {
          UCB0IE &= ~UCRXIE;
          MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
        }
        break;
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
        switch (MasterMode)
        {
          case TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE:
              UCB0TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
              if (RXByteCtr)
                  MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE;   // Need to start receiving now
              else
                  MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;        // Continue to transmision with the data in Transmit Buffer
              break;

          case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
              UCB0IE |= UCRXIE;              // Enable RX interrupt
              UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE;             // Disable TX interrupt
              UCB0CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;            // Switch to receiver
              MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE;    // State state is to receive data
              UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;          // Send repeated start
              if (RXByteCtr == 1)
              {
                  //Must send stop since this is the N-1 byte
                  while((UCB0CTLW0 & UCTXSTT));
                  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;      // Send stop condition
              }
              break;

          case TX_DATA_MODE:
              if (TXByteCtr)
              {
                  UCB0TXBUF = TransmitBuffer[TransmitIndex++];
                  TXByteCtr--;
              }
              else
              {
                  //Done with transmission
                  UCB0CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;     // Send stop condition
                  MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                  UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE;                       // disable TX interrupt
                  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
              }
              break;

          default:
              __no_operation();
              break;
        }
        break;
    default: break;
  }
}
```

---

Debugging from oscilloscope:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see from the photos, the Slave does transmit an ACK, and the Master a NACK, however, it is not in the code (presumed it is sent and received by the master).

Is the I2C working fine? Is there still a problem with the I2C program of the MSP430? or I need to configure something in the MAX30102 first?

---

Comment: Did you try to start your code without an IDE debugger? Does an oscilloscope show any difference between a direct mode and a debugging mode?

Comment: No, actually I started it with the debugger, in the IDE (Code Composer Studio), in order to run the code, you need to press the debug button and run the code.

I am not sure what you mean by direct mode or debugging mode, my oscilloscope is Hantek DSO5102P

Comment: I mean try to start it without debugger (not step-by-step and without breakpoints).

Comment: I just run it without debugging and used the oscilloscope to capture the signal, still no change, and `UCB0RXBUF = 0x00`. I will post what I found in the scope in the edit

Comment: The problem in the MAX30102 datasheet doesn't clearly mention what to expect when we write to it or want to read from it. Can we only do one interaction? Do we need to finish the whole interaction to see the result? Do we need to configure the IC before using  it?I tried testing it, writing `0x0A` to the `FIFO_WR_PTR` and then reading data from it, I got `0x00`

Comment: Are you checking for slave ACK after sending each byte? If so I don't see it in your code (or your pseudocode). Should be a test of UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG somewhere in the code. Slave ACK is your indication that communication is working OK! If you don't get ACK where expected, the master must stop the transaction.

Comment: Slave ACK occurs when Master is transmitting, I  thought according the the diagram in the edit, I assumed that when a Slave ACK occurs, `UCTXIFG0` is set, and I interpret that as a Slave ACK.